# Mongodb import error

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I'm ran into a problem using dump/restore to move a MongoDB database from my local machine to the MongoHQ.com.  When I restore the dump to MongoHQ it is missing about 10% of the documents with no apparent errors.

To troubleshoot I though I would use export/import locally to validate the data and I am getting a error on import, the export did not report any errors. I used json format for the export.  Here is one of the import errors;

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Date milliseconds overflow: offset:10357
```

It reports errors on 726 documents out of about 130k.  Based on the error I think it is having problems with a date field but I cant figure out how to find the problem documents.  I tried doing a repair with no luck.
Anyone have an idea to try to find what's wrong?

Comment: Can you try using --objcheck with mongorestore. Maybe also --verbose

Comment: Good suggestion, it restored with no errors using the --objcheck option but the export/import is still reporting the same errors on import.  I'll see if I can find a tool to open the 450mb JSON file and see if I can find dates that don't look right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question again, hopefully it helps someone else.

The problem occurs on any document with dates before Jan 1 1970, the Unix epoch.  I am assuming that dump/restore handles it okay but not export/import because dump/restore is using BSON and import/export uses JSON or CSV.  This is an unresolved bug report for MongoDB https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-961.

As a footnote, I initially loaded my MongoDB using Mongoid from Ruby which was apparently able to handle those pre 1970 dates.

Comment: Great thanks for the update. Please vote on that issue to get it fixed.